# Query a Google Spreadsheets using several different values

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to figure out how to update the following Google Spreadsheets query function so it can search column "J" for three or more separate values. If any of the values are present in column "J", I need the query to return the 'select' data in column B, C, D, etc.

```
=query(data!B2:BK,"select B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, BA where J = 'Guest Speaker'",false)
```

So if "J" equals `Guest Speaker` or `Field Trip` or `Anything`, it will return data from B, C, D, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [query language documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#where) says,

> You can join multiple conditions using the logical operators and, or, and not. Parentheses can be used to define explicit precedence.

Example:

```
select * where J = 'Guest Speaker' or J = 'Field Trip' or J = 'Anything'
```

Comment: is it possible to allow for any of the three but 'require' one of them? So it can be any of the three in column "J", but it also MUST to be something else in column "K".
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you mean like `(J = 'this' or J = 'that' or J = 'another') and K = 'this one'`?

Comment: Thank you Zaq! I wasn't sure if or where I could use () to do that. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. It does say "Parentheses can be used to define explicit precedence."  in the doc part I quoted.